# Select Distinct record in LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq

I have comming multiple records in strongly typed list. I want distinct record with all columns based on AssessmentID column so for example I am getting two records with AssessmentID = 2455 so I want pick 2455 once in list

```
List<AssessmentWithRemidiationViewModel> activeAssessmentWithRemidiation = AssessmentRemidiationRelay.GetActiveAssessmentWithRemediation(null);
var query_b = (from b in activeAssessmentWithRemidiation
               where ((b.AssessorID == ContextSession.StaffID) 
                        || (b.ModuleLead == ContextSession.StaffID) 
                        || (b.SeniorStaffID == ContextSession.StaffID)) 
                        && b.ClinicalSupervisorCheck == true
                    select b).ToList();
```

well as no one can answer this so they mark as duplicate, any way I found asnwer and is as following;

### My Answer

```
  var query_b = (from b in activeAssessmentWithRemidiation
                      where ((b.AssessorID == ContextSession.StaffID) || (b.ModuleLead == ContextSession.StaffID) || (b.SeniorStaffID == ContextSession.StaffID)) && b.ClinicalSupervisorCheck == true
                      select b).ToList();


       var filteredList = query_b.GroupBy(x => x.AssessmentID)
                          .Select(i=>i.First()).ToList();
```

Comment: What is the question

Comment: There's a contradiction. You want distinct records according to all columns but also according to a single column `AssessmentID`.

Comment: Have a look at MoreLINQ's `DistinctBy`: https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs

Comment: I am getting records with repeating AssessmentID. for example 255 (2 times) 3552( 4 times) , so in my list I want to pick two records one with assessmentID 255 and 2nd 3552

Comment: I have found answer, check my question update above